# How can I mock a function being called in a GraphQL resolver using Jest?

Tags: jestjs, graphql, mocking

I'm trying to mock a db call inside a resolver. The resolver does some business logic on the db call so I can't just mock the resolver itself. I could unit test the business logic but this test needs to be more involved than that.

What is occurring is the mocked function gets called, but the output gets overwritten by the `mocks` object defaults.

I've tried to mock the db call a few different ways, by mocking the module and by just mocking the function, but both ways get overwritten by the `mocks` object. This is with `mockEntireSchema: false`.

I'll try to keep the minimum reproducible example short.

`resolvers.ts`

```
import db from './db.ts'

export default {
  Query: {
    getUserDomain: async (_: object, { id }: { id: string }, { dataSources }: Record<string, SQLDataSource>) => {
      const email = await db.getUser(id);
      return getDomain(email);
    }
  }
}
```

`db.ts`

```
class Db extends SQLDataSource {
  getUser(email: string) {
    return this.knex
      .select('*')
      .from('users')
      .where({ id })
      .cache(MINUTE);
  }
}
const knexConfig = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    ...config,
  },
};

export default new UserDb(knexConfig);
```

`typeDefs.ts`

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Domain {
    domain: String!
  }

  type Query {
    getUserDomain(id: String!): Domain!
  }
}

export default typeDefs
```

So at this point I need to mock `getUser` and query `getUserDomain`

`test.js`

```
import db from './db.ts'
import resolvers from './resolvers.ts'
import typeDefs from './typeDefs.ts'

import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const INT_MOCK = 1;
const FLOAT_MOCK = 1.1;
const STRING_MOCK = 'mockedString';

const mocks = {
  Int: () => INT_MOCK,
  Float: () => FLOAT_MOCK,
  String: () => STRING_MOCK,
};

const QUERY_GET_USER_DOMAIN = gql`
  query getUserDomain {
    getUserDomain(id: "foo") {
      domain
    }
  }
`;

jest.mock('./db.ts', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./db.ts');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
      ...originalModule,
      getUser: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
          console.log('inside');
          return "foo@gmail.com";
        })
    },
  };
});

let server;
describe('resolvers', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    server = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
      mocks,
      mockEntireSchema: false,
      dataSources: () => ({ db }),
    });
  });
  describe('getUserDomain', () => {
    it('Mocks getUserDomain', async () => {
      const res = await server.executeOperation({ query: QUERY_GET_USER_DOMAIN });
      expect(res.data.getUserDomain.domain).toBe("gmail");
    });
  });
});
```

With this `res.data.getUserDomain.domain` returns `mockedString`, but I see 'inside' being console.log'd so I know at least getUser is being mocked and getting called within the query, but the result "gmail" is getting overwritten with "mockedString".

My node version is 14.18.1 and my tsconfig lib/target are set to es2018. Thank you for reading, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the return from a string to an object[]. I wasn't properly matching the return type from getUser, so my getDomain(string) was returning the default.

```
getUser: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce(() => {
          return [{email: "foo@gmail.com"}];
        })
```